# How much have Western countries pushed back on Thailand's lese-majeste laws to date?

Tags: thailand

[Thailand: Man jailed for 50 years for defaming monarchy](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-68020494)

> A Thai court has sentenced a man to 50 years in jail for comments deemed to have defamed the monarchy - the highest ever sentence handed down under the country's notorious lese majeste law.
>
> Thirty-year-old Mongkol Thirakot was originally sentenced to 28 years for posts he made three years ago on Facebook.
> But on Thursday an appeals court added an extra 22 years to the sentence.

I recall someone also got hard jail time for [insulting the royal dog](https://time.com/4148911/thailand-bhumibol-tongdaeng-lese-majeste/).

> Authorities arrested factory worker Thanakorn Siripaiboon at his home in suburban Bangkok last week and charged him with writing a “sarcastic” Internet post about Tongdaeng, the mongrel owned by King Bhumibol Adulyadej, as well as with sedition and insulting the King, reports the New York Times

Not to mention that their elections don't seem all that kosher.

What's the most severe consequence/sanction Thailand has received to date from Western countries?  Plenty of them tend to find ways to punish excessive behavior by dictatorships.  See for example Venezuela.

Any of this happen, ever, with Thailand?  Sanctions, military cooperation suspension, arms embargos, ambassador recalls?